# How to find IP address using multicast_dns in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a flutter application. To make life easier for end users I decided to find services running on a Raspberry Pi.

Avahi is running and working. I can use different mdns application to find the service and hostname AND IP for the host.

Flutter have a multicast_dns package but I cant find a way to get the IP of the host.
Can anyone help??

Comment: Sorry if my language not are up to your expectations. Why do you assume that I not have tried?? I have spent hours trying to understand and find a solution. Even tried to understand the code in the package.

Comment: I assumed that because you did not show any of this effort in the question. It's important to show your effort in the question, not just say you have an issue and couldn't figure it out. SO is not a help desk.

Comment: Ok,, I will do better next time. Can you "help" ?

Comment: You still have the opportunity to fix your current question with edits. Add what you have tried, anything that you've found, specific roadblocks you've run into. Again, even if help is in quotes, SO is not a help desk and see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of googling I have found a way to get the IP from the hostname. There is a method to resolve hostnames (`ResourceRecordQuery.addressIPv4(srv.target)`):

```
  await for (final PtrResourceRecord ptr in client.lookup<PtrResourceRecord>(
      ResourceRecordQuery.serverPointer(serviceType))) {
    print('PTR: ${ptr.toString()}');

    await for (final SrvResourceRecord srv in client.lookup<SrvResourceRecord>(
        ResourceRecordQuery.service(ptr.domainName))) {
      print('SRV target: ${srv.target} port: ${srv.port}');

      // Resolve the IP with this line
      await for (final IPAddressResourceRecord ip
          in client.lookup<IPAddressResourceRecord>(
              ResourceRecordQuery.addressIPv4(srv.target))) {
        print('IP: ${ip.address.toString()}');
      }
    }
```

I found this solution on a [github thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75585).